# Can a Bluetooth tag (iOS and Android) send a push notification without the device being connected to the internet?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, beacons, eddystone

I have several Bluetooth tags, model "Onyx Beacon One". They can be controlled via the company's CMS.

I can also switch them between Eddystone UID&URL and iBeacon. I can simply place two of them next to each other to send messages to both iOS and Android devices.

Using the company's iOS App, I could update the tags with the settings from the CMS (if I had an iPhone).

I have three beacons. Two of them are set to iBeacon mode and one of them is set to Eddystone. They are all set to push a URL to any devices in range.

Unfortunately, only those devices which are connected to the internet receive these notifications. Android devices only receive them if you turn on the screen for a few seconds. I don't have an iPhone for testing yet, so I had to use my coworker's for setting up the config.

Bluetooth obviously has to be enabled for any passerbys, but what about location services, an internet connection and other requirements?

Comment: *I don't think so, but I'm not sure that's why it is a comment.* The bluetooth tags only send their UUID's to bypassers. Your phone has to get that UUID, send it to your company CMS, get the corresponding message for that UUID and return it to your phone as notification. This is how we made it in my previous job.